# Need to know the configuration files to be modified in CD server

Tags: configuration, site-configuration

I have installed Sitecore 9.1 XP scaled(XP1) topology using PowerShell script shared in installation guide. I have `sitecore.cm`, `sitecore.cd` and other app process installed (REP,PRC,etc).

When i browse CD app(`sitecore91.cd`) i see following error

```
Exception Details: System.InvalidOperationException: Could not find configuration node: contentSearch/indexConfigurations/indexUpdateStrategies/syncMaster" in "CD"
```

I renamed some of the config in `\App_Config\Sitecore` like `marketing automation.XX.config` to make CD work.

Later I got

```
"Server Error in '/' Application.
Could not find configuration node: databases/database[@id='master']"
```

My query: What are all the config files that has to be modified for smooth running of CD. I could see from config that its pointing to master DB. is there a patch to change all the default database to web in CD?

Appreciate any help.

Comment: have you checked what the role is defined as on your CD servers? Now the config is role based, you shouldn't need to be disabling any configs for CD.

Comment: And the server role is defined in the web.config

Comment: If you have configured everything as per installation guideline and passed right parameters in JSON for CD instance, then it simply works without changing any configuration post installation. It looks like you missed some steps or passed any wrong value during installation.